# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un array de `n` elementos, los cuales se obtienen con `n` peticiones asíncronas?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

### Contexto

Tenemos una vista de ofertas en el frontal que tiene este aspecto:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let offer of offerList">
      <td>{{offer[0].appArea.creationDate}}</td>
      <td>{{offer[0].client.id}}</td>
      <td>{{offer[0].client.name}}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Esta `offerlist` se recoge de una base de datos de una forma *menos tradicional*: se guardan en la base de datos
únicamente los ids y un hash, con el que se accede a una red IPFS que es la que tiene los datos de las ofertas.

Además, está montado de tal manera que, para obtener un array de `n` ofertas, se hacen exactamente `n + 1` peticiones:
la primera trae el array con los ids y hash, y las `n` siguientes son resultado de iterar por ese array y pedir a la
IPFS los datos:

```js
export class OffersComponent implements OnInit{

  offerList: Array<any> = []

  loadOffersForClient(email) {

    this.offerService.getOwnerInitialOffers(email).subscribe(
      (initOfferResponse) => {
        initOfferResponse[0].offers.map((item) => {

          this.offerService.getOfferFileData(item.hashId).subscribe(
            (itemResponse) => {
              this.offerList.push([itemResponse, item, ]);
            }
          );
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

El servicio hace simples llamadas con el cliente http:

```js
export class OfferService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOwnerInitialOffers(email: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`path/to/offers/${email}`); // se traen datos por post porque asi esta especificada la api
  }

  getOfferFileData(hashId: string) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`path/to/file/server/${hashId}`);
  }
}
```

### Problema

Los requerimientos han cambiado y necesitamos ordenar el array. Por fecha, para ser más exactos. El problema viene por que
**no tengo claro cuándo puedo ordenar el array estando seguro de que los elementos han terminado de llenarse**.

Hasta ahora, se me había ocurrido ordenarlo por fuerza bruta, cada vez que se lanza una nueva petición:

```js
this.offerService.getOfferFileData(item.hashId).subscribe(
  (itemResponse) => {
    this.offerList.push([itemResponse, item, ]);
    this.offerList.sort((a, b) => {
      const firstDate = a[0].applicationArea.creationDateTime;
      const secondDate = b[0].applicationArea.creationDateTime;
      return (firstDate < secondDate) ? 1 : ((firstDate > secondDate) ? -1 : 0);
    });
  }
);
```

Aparte de ser increíblemente ineficiente, no funciona, entiendo que los elementos no han sido cargados para cuando
la ordenación se produce.

**¿Cómo puedo asegurarme de que el array ya ha sido cargado, para poder ordenar una sola vez y sin peligro de que entren nuevos elementos?**

Comment: Puedes intentar convertír tus dos servicios en promesas y ejecutarlas dentro de `Promise.all([ tuObservable().toPromise()]).then()` (poner los dos observables). Así obtienes un arreglo con los datos cuando todo termine de cargarse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes usar la función de RxJs [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html):

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
...


let observables=[];
observables.push(this.http.get(URL1));
observables.push(this.http.get(URL2));
observables.push(this.http.get(URL3));
observables.push(this.http.get(URL4));
forkJoin(observables, arrayOfValues => { this.offerList = arrayOfValues.sort(...)});
```

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
const { from,forkJoin } = rxjs;
const {map} = rxjs.operators;

//Por simplificar, creo un Observable desde una promesa
function getObservableAjax(url) {
  return from(fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()))
      .pipe(map(elem => elem.name)); //de cada respuesta, nos quedamos con el campo name
}

function getCharactersFromStarWars() {
    let observables=[];
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      observables.push(getObservableAjax(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${i}/`));
    }
    return forkJoin(observables);
}

getCharactersFromStarWars().subscribe(elements => {
  elements.sort(); 
  console.log(elements);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.7/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-0/2ebe9lI6BcinFBXFjbBkquDfccT2wP+E48pecciFuGMXPRNdInXZawHiM2NUUVJ4/aKAzyebbvh+CkvRhwTA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```